# Setting up Backbone router

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, url-routing

Can't figure out what's going wrong with my Backbone router. Can anyone spot a mistake in the following block of code?  The index route is working fine but the classes route isn't ever triggering (e.g. when I navigate to a URL like `localhost/classes/test`)

```
var app = app || {};

$(function() {


    app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '' : 'index',
            'classes/:id' : 'classes'
        },

        initialize: function() {
            this.classList = new app.ClassCollection();
        },

        index: function() {
            this.menuView = new app.ClassCollectionView({collection: this.classList});
        },

        classes: function(id) {
            console.log("hello")
            var _class = new app.ClassModel({id: id});
            this.classView = new app.ClassPageView({model: _class});
        }
    });

    router = new app.Router();
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
})
```

If everything looks in order, there's probably a bug somewhere else in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone.router is extending hashbang navigation.
so 
     localhost/#classes/test

should lead to your method. ALSO! pay attention that emty route should be at the end of the routes list.
It's like else if construction, if route matches "" (default # ?!) it will never match other routes

Answer (score 0):

by default the route will work  with the hash  try localhost/#classes/test